# How to get a textbox by its name in gwt

Tags: gwt

Lets say I have a layout panel having multiple textboxes.

Now I want to get a particular textbox in that panel by its name. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to paste the relevant part of your code to clarify what you're attempting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to keep references of the textboxes in a hashMap while you create them.
You need to be careful about memory leaks though.
Another way is to use [GWtQuery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). You could access then by name any element in the DOM.

To get it without without GWTQuery you can do that:

```
Element element = Document.get().getElementById("myTextboxID");
TextBox box = new TextBox();
box.wrap(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since gwt has not a css-selector implementation, I would use gwtquery aka gquery whose selector implementation performs really well.

Apart from many other features, it is able to return the widget asociated with any element:

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

[...]

// if the textbox is already a widget 
TextBox b = $("input[name=first_name]").widget();

//Or it its an element
TextBox b = TextBox.wrap($("input[name=search]").get(0));   

b.setValue("Foo");
```