# GWT get certain textbox

Tags: gwt

I have a complex ui with panels which are removed/added depending on the stage of the application.

What I want on a concrete event is to get the value of a certain textbox if it is attached.

The problem is that this textbox has not an unique instance, the only thing which i know about them is their name: 'search'. Is there a way to perform this?.

Comment: On what event type you want to fetch the value of the textbox?

Comment: I have a `PushButton` in a UI corner which when pushed filters things displayed, so the code to get the boxes would be in the clickhancler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gquery code returns all attached `TexBoxes` with the name 'search'

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
...

List<TextBox> boxes = $("input[name=search]").widgets(TextBox.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645031/how-to-get-a-textbox-by-its-name-in-gwt/13651975#13651975) in stackoverflow, focus on the second answer.

```
$("input[name=first_name]")
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, finally I selected the other answer since it is just what I was looking for.